# How to mock HttpClient.send() with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a method that send  an HTTPRequest:

```
public String myMethod(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException, HttpTimeoutException {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    return response.body();
}
```

I’m trying to mock the method `send`  To create a test for this method.
I just didn’t find yet how to mock `HttpClient.newHttpClient()`.
This is one version for the test (isn’t working)

```
 void checkGetEarningRulesByTypeReturnGoodValues() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String expectedRes = "...";

        HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
        HttpResponse<Object> httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
        when(httpResponse.body()).thenReturn(expectedRes);
        when(httpClient.send(any(), any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(HttpClient.newHttpClient()).thenReturn(httpClient);

        String res = MyClass.myMethod(url);

        assertEquals(res, expectedRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me you need to use mockito-inline for mocking static methods:

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() throws IOException, InterruptedException, HttpTimeoutException {
    // Arrange
    String url = "https://example.com/api";
    String expectedResponse = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}";

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    Mockito.when(httpResponse.body()).thenReturn(expectedResponse);

    HttpClient httpClientMock = Mockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
    try(MockedStatic<HttpClient> httpClientMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(HttpClient.class)) {
        httpClientMockedStatic.when(HttpClient::newHttpClient).thenReturn(httpClientMock);
        Mockito.when(httpClientMock.send(Mockito.any(HttpRequest.class), ArgumentMatchers.<HttpResponse.BodyHandler<String>>any()))
                .thenReturn(httpResponse);

        String actualResponse = MyClass.myMethod(url);

        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResponse, actualResponse);
    }

}
```

The try-with-resource block is used to make the static mock remains temporary, so it's mocked only within that scope.

When not using a try block, make sure to close the mock, once you are done with the assertions.

**NOTE: mocking STATIC METHODS requires mockito-inline dependency instead of mockito-core.**

My pom dependency for mockit0-inline:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```